# Different behavior when marshaling structures in 32 bit than in 64 bit runtimes

Tags: c#, winapi, data-structures, pinvoke, marshalling

I discovered this when I was PInvoking [SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The C++ function signature is:

```
HDEVINFO SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(
  _In_opt_ const GUID *ClassGuid,
  _In_opt_       HWND hwndParent
);
```

In C# I have defined the `GUID` structure like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct GUID
{
    public uint Data1;
    public ushort Data2;
    public ushort Data3;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public byte[] Data4;
}
```

and the function like this:

```
[DllImport("Setupapi.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(GUID ClassGuid, IntPtr hwndParent);
```

Since in C# structures are passed by copy by default (unlike classes) this function signature should not match. And indeed when calling the function on 32-bit runtime:

```
GUID classGuid = new GUID();
IntPtr deviceInfoSet = SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(classGuid, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I get an error:

> SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely
>   because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged
>   target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of
>   the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

But on 64-bit runtime the code above works. Why ???

Of course, if I pass the structure by reference instead, the function works correctly on both 32-bit and 64-bit runtimes:

```
[DllImport("Setupapi.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(ref GUID ClassGuid, IntPtr hwndParent);

GUID classGuid = new GUID();
IntPtr deviceInfoSet = SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(ref classGuid, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: @PeterDuniho On x64 I receive a valid pointer to a device info set. I developed this on 64-bit environment, and the the driver installed successfully every time. I only discovered the bad function signature when I decided to test on a 32-bit environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The x64 calling convention is *very* different from the x86 conventions.  You'll find an overview in [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235286.aspx).  Essential part is:

> Any argument that doesn’t fit in 8 bytes, or is not 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, must be passed by reference.

An x64 compiler enforces this requirement when necessary, creating a copy of the struct and passing a pointer to it when the program passes such a struct by value.  In this case the pinvoke marshaller takes care of it.  So, no stack imbalance.